# Changing the selections made on a website using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify some selections on a website using Python before scraping the site with BeautifulSoup. As an example, there is a calendar range on this one website that determines the time range on which a table is constructed, and you have to hit apply after choosing the range. So I guess my question involves both modifying the source code and then hitting a button, any ideas? Hopefully this was somewhat clear

Comment: I guess the table is loaded dynamically with javascript? You could use [`Selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to load the site, click the button and pass the result to `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you with the question. I first save the entire site into variable using BeautifulSoup and then find all the table elements inside it. I will give Selenium a go, thanks!